# Accessing Node of Scene in Engine Source, where can this happen?

Tags: godot

Say we have a scene that starts with a spatial node named `Node_of_interest` with a child `Mesh_of_interest`, is there somewhere in the source code where we can access these nodes?

I assumed the SceneTree would be the right place to start since it has [`Node * current_scene`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/c02325ffda2258172385e70e160cd476fb19a004/scene/main/scene_tree.h#L169) , but when I step through in the debugger on a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/c02325ffda2258172385e70e160cd476fb19a004/scene/main/scene_tree.cpp#L483)
I never see `current_scene` as not null.

I feel like with this information I'll have a much better handle on how the nodes relate to servers and drivers.

[image]

Here's the scene that I'm trying this on.
[image]

Comment: using `get_edited_scene_root` was suggested in the contributor chat, and it appears that we can verify that the `Node` we receive a pointer to is the correct one by looking into the Node's data member which is a StringName, and then to the name field which holds a sequence of characters matching the values typed in the editor.

Comment: Yes, if you want this to work in the editor then using `get_edited_scene_root` makes sense. I haven't worked with that in C++. Does it work? - I would expect that trying to get there from the main loop, in the editor, means going through all the nodes of the editor, until you reach the edited scene, I don't know exactly where, if I were to figure it out, I would use `get_edited_scene_root` and query the path. - About how Nodes relate to Servers… their classes call into them. For example, if you see the code in `mesh_instance.cpp`, you will find it uses `VisualServer::get_singleton()`.